# Cannot use memcache in rails localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2, memcached

I am using rails 3.2.13 for development and would use memcache to cache user information. A gem 'dalli' could help to simply the cache process. However, when I run console `Rails.cache.write('alice', 'bob')`, it always returns `false`. Then, I run `Rails.cache.read('alice')` and output `nil`.

I ensure setting in config as below but no hope.

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_classes = true
```

Do I forget to set something? Please give advice. Thanks!